# Trace of the points of intersection of two moving curves

Tags: plotting

I would like to trace the points of intersection between the polar curves

```
r == Cos[n θ + k t]
```

and

```
r == t Csc[θ]
```

as `t` goes from -1 to 1. (`n` and `k` are constants, and `y`, `r`, and `θ` relate in the usual way.)

Note the the 2nd is equivalent to `y == t`.

Here is a GIF (taken from [this article](http://resourcemagonline.com/2015/11/why-your-camera-makes-airplane-propellers-look-so-weird/60421/)) to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: example]

(I really only need the equivalent of the final frame.)

Since it is not possible to obtain a closed-form solution, one would have to find the intersections numerically. While it is possible to sample a bunch of points, doing so would result in just that: a bunch of points, when what I was looking for was something like an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would this plot suffice?

```
ContourPlot[
    Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == Cos[5 ArcTan[x,y] + 17 y - 1],
    {x, -1, 1},
    {y, -1, 1},
    PlotPoints->100
]
```

[image]

Comment: *facepalm* Yes. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: Please, could you explain how to get to this equation?

Comment: @pH13, `r=Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` and `θ=ArcTan[x,y]`. He's just making both equations equal to each other and using ContourPlot to find the intersection.